# Configuring MapBox Map Widget?

Tags: mapbox, ckan

I follow the instructions to set up the MapBox Map Widget and set these variables inside my configuration file, but the MapBox map widget only works when I upload and view GeoJSON files, When I upload a csv file and plot the points using latitude and longitude, it still uses the MapQuest Map Widget Base Layer, any idea why that is happening? I thought I'm changing the base layers for all maps by changing these variables. I have also checked to make sure that mapquest isn't defined anywhere in the configuration file.

```
 ckanext.spatial.common_map.type = mapbox
 ckanext.spatial.common_map.mapbox.map_id = youraccount.map-xxxxxxxx
```

http://docs.ckan.org/projects/ckanext-spatial/en/latest/map-widgets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently that geo-related plugin does not [support map previews of CSV files](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/ckanext-spatial/en/latest/previews.html).

Comment: I can display maps though through uploaded CSV Files just not using the geo-related plugin, there is built-in functionality into the core of CKAN that allows me to pick different columns of data as the latitude and longitude and it will show each point on the map which uses a mapquest plugin, I get 3 tabs in the data viewer when I upload a CSV file, a table tab, a graph tab and a map tab, so I need to go into the code and change the core map plugin to mapbox instead of mapquest

Comment: thanks you answered my question though because now I realize I was looking in the wrong spot